# JHipster integration with custom theme

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, metronic

I am trying to use custom theme with JHipster (Metronic theme if does it matter).
I followed the advice how to add css and js https://stackoverflow.com/a/42070788/9026582

But when running `npm run webpack:build` webpack build does not compile.
I got error like this (there were more similar to the one below, posting only one for simplicity):

```
ERROR in /home/robert/workspace/robo/src/main/webapp/app/content/layout/aside/aside-left.component.ts
(105,76): Cannot find name 'mUtil'.
```

I've done some research and find out that probably declaration types file is missing. Found it among the theme and copied to JHipster project. The file looks like that:

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
    id: string;
}

declare var mMenu: any;
declare var mOffcanvas: any;
declare var mScrollTop: any;
declare var mHeader: any;
declare var mToggle: any;
declare var mQuicksearch: any;
declare var mUtil: any;
declare var mPortlet: any;
```

Now webpack build compiles, but there are problems when rendering the site.
Styling works fine, but scripts are not correctly loaded and in browser console I can see errors (again omitting similar ones):

```
HeaderComponent.html:1 ERROR ReferenceError: mUtil is not defined
    at HeaderDirective.ngAfterViewInit (header.directive.ts?6754:56)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js?09c9:9568)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js?09c9:9542)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js?09c9:9532)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js?09c9:10468)
    at callViewAction (core.js?09c9:10700)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js?09c9:10642)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js?09c9:10465)
    at callViewAction (core.js?09c9:10700)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js?09c9:10663)
```

There is `mUtil` occurence in theme file `scripts.bundle.js`, but I import that file in JHipster's `vendors.ts`.
I've checked what webpack build gives me. Inside `main.bundle.js` I found `mUtil` occurence so it should be loaded when rendering the site.

I am looking for any help as I do not have knowledge or idea how to make it work.